# Jackson serialization with JsonTypeInfo appends "_$$_javassist_1" to the class and don't know what is causing it?

Tags: java, json, jackson-databind

Jackson serialization with JsonTypeInfo results with a class hint appended with **"_$$_javassist_1"**, For example if the class is Dog it serializes it as 
   `"@class" : "Dog_$$_javassist_1"` 
and I have no idea what is causing the problem. The expected outcome is
  `"@class" : "Dog"`

The **@JsonTypeInfo** annotation that is put on the abstract super class looks like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"handle"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "iri")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public abstract class Animal {
...
}
```

Comment: Are the getters correctly declared in your class?

Comment: Are you sure that the objects you are actually serializing are (real) `Dog` objects ... and not proxies generated by some framework that you are using?

Comment: This is absolutely a case of proxy objects, and a good option here is to use `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` instead.

Comment: Yes After further inspection of  the 'Dog' object, It appears that it is indeed a proxy object. However changing the JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME from JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS did not resolve the issue. @Guillaume F, getters are declared for the classes

Comment: Accessing the getters should resolve the proxy if the transaction is still open.